# Change time_submit for pickadate.js

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

## I'm SOLVED!

Solve: https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/#formats_use_hidden_only

My wish POST request format:
`...date=17/04/2021&time=00:31`

Created by Datepicker.js POST request format:
`...date=17 April, 2021&date_submit=17/04/2021&time=10:00 AM&time_submit=10:00`

I have to remove the date-time values and replace the *_submit with time or date

My code:

```
                            var today = new Date();
                            var dd = today.getDate();
                            var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
                            var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
                            if (dd < 10) {
                                dd = '0' + dd;
                            }
                            if (mm < 10) {
                                mm = '0' + mm;
                            }
                            today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

                            var $input = $('.datepicker').pickadate({
                                formatLabel: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                                formatSubmit: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
                                closeOnSelect: true,
                                closeOnClear: false,
                            })
                            var $picker2 = $('.timepicker').pickatime({
                                timePicker24Hour: true,
                                formatLabel: 'H:i',
                                formatSubmit: 'H:i',
                            })
                            var picker2 = $picker2.pickatime('picker2')
                            picker2.open()
```

Comment: I don't know if Datepicker.js allows that. But you can write your own formatter function to achieve that.

Comment: How can i write own formatter func? My knowledge of javascript is very limited. Normally I develop django.